# What's the most effective way of making 'night mode' in CSS?

Tags: php, html, css, darkmode

I wanna make a website with 'day' and 'night mode', basically just light and dark version of a website and I have no clue how to do it the best way.

I've tried just making two HTML files with different CSS's included, then i tried changing CSS using PHP.

None of my tries were satisfying, I need something universal and easy to implement.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

The best way is probably to use the `prefers-color-scheme` media feature in CSS.

Example from
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme

```css
.day   { background: #eee; color: black; }
.night { background: #333; color: white; }

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  .day.dark-scheme   { background:  #333; color: white; }
  .night.dark-scheme { background: black; color:  #ddd; }
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
  .day.light-scheme   { background: white; color:  #555; }
  .night.light-scheme { background:  #eee; color: black; }
}

.day, .night {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 7em;
  height: 2em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="day">Day (initial)</div>
<div class="day light-scheme">Day (changes in light scheme)</div>
<div class="day dark-scheme">Day (changes in dark scheme)</div> <br>

<div class="night">Night (initial)</div>
<div class="night light-scheme">Night (changes in light scheme)</div>
<div class="night dark-scheme">Night (changes in dark scheme)</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in `prefers-color-scheme` media feature
It will goes with the user operating system setting (e.g. light or dark mode) or a user agent setting.
[read more about the topic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme)

Here's a simple example on how to create custom style for dark mode:

```css
body {
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  body {
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
This is a simple paragraph
</p>
```

Or you can do a custom styling without relaying on the user system preferences like the example below :

```js
function toggleDarkMode() {
  document.body.classList.toggle('dark');
}
```

```css
body {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}

.dark {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<p>
This is an example paragraph
</p>
<button onclick="toggleDarkMode()">Toggle dark mode</button>
```

It can be improved by storing the dark mode/light mode to the localStorage